# Cant migrate because of foreign key in ruby on tails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

Im using ruby on rails and trying to do migration.
but it comes to error when i run rake db:migrate

my migration files 20190613073017_create_jasas.rb

```
class CreateJasas < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :jasas do |t|
      t.string :code
      t.string :name
      t.string :image
      t.boolean :top, default: false
      t.boolean :new, default: true
      t.string :slug
      t.references :jasa_department, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :jasa_category, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.integer :price
      t.text :description
      t.references :vendor, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.integer :minimum_order
      t.string :short_description
      t.boolean :catalogue, default: false
      t.boolean :etalase, default: false
      t.integer :availability, default: 0
      t.integer :old_price
      t.integer :discount, default: 0
      t.boolean :status, default: true
      t.boolean :sample, default: true
      t.boolean :stock, default: true
      t.integer :views_counter, default: 0

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :jasas, :slug, unique: true
    add_index :jasas, :code, unique: true
    add_index :jasas, :name
    add_index :jasas, :availability
    add_index :jasas, :new
    add_index :jasas, :minimum_order
    add_index :jasas, :old_price
    add_index :jasas, :price
    add_index :jasas, :created_at
  end
end
```

ang this is my error message

```
== 20190613073017 CreateJasas: migrating ======================================
-- create_table(:jasas)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: Cannot add foreign key constraint: ALTER TABLE `jasas` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_f1d155c570`
FOREIGN KEY (`jasa_department_id`)
  REFERENCES `jasa_departments` (`id`)
/home/lukni/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:305:in `query'
```

hope there is onyone can help me

Comment: yes but migration after jasa tables

Comment: ive try to migrate jasa_department first but still stuck

Comment: the response still the same with StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: Cannot add foreign key constraint: ALTER TABLE `jasas` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_f1d155c570`
FOREIGN KEY (`jasa_department_id`)
  REFERENCES `jasa_departments` (`id`)

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this [link](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/30806).

A possible reason is that there is a mismatch of types of the referenced fields.
( `id` of `jasa_department` might be `int` while by default, this line `t.references :jasa_department, index: true, foreign_key: true` expect it is `bigint` )

Can u try edit that line to

```
t.references :jasa_department, index: true, foreign_key: true, type: :integer
```

Answer (score 0):

First, don't index every column.
Next, I think one of table you references not exist or your constraint on these tables existed.